# Cannot install scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, fedora

I wanted to install scikit-learn, but I cannot do it. I use newest Fedora. To install scikit-learn I do.

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

I receive errors:

```
    g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/liblinear.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/tron.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/linear.o -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4 -lcblas -lm -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/liblinear.cpython-34m.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    error: Command "g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/liblinear.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/tron.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/src/liblinear/linear.o -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4 -lcblas -lm -lpython3.4m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/sklearn/svm/liblinear.cpython-34m.so" failed with exit status 1
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/mstankiewicz/.virtualenvs/sus/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4scm2pb_/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8fh7u6fy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mstankiewicz/.virtualenvs/sus/include/site/python3.4/scikit-learn" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4scm2pb_/scikit-learn
```

I tried to install atlas as I found on google, but it did not helped

```
sudo dnf -y install atlas3gf-base atlas-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem installing on Fedora 24.

Atlas changed their libraries. See [Fedora Mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2013-September/189467.html).

Thankfully, there is a package in fedora's repo, run:

```
# dnf install python2-scikit-learn.x86_64
```

Comment: Nice workaround, also, this works for python3:

`dnf install python3-scikit-learn`

But still looking for a way to install from pip...

Answer (score -1):

You might need to install some dependencies first.

```
sudo dnf install atlas lapack atlas-devel blas-devel gcc-gfortran jupyter ipython fftw fftw-devel
```

**Edit**: The best practice is to use virtual python environment management. You can install Annaconda to do it.

Comment: It's not enough, still the same dependency problem.

Comment: @Sylvain  Maybe you can try Annaconda. It's the best practice to me.

Comment: I need to remotely deploy through fabric so anaconda is not an option yet. I removed Fedora and installed Ubuntu gnome instead. That did the trick.